# Force One of Two Method Implementations In A Child Class

Tags: c#, methods, implementation, abstract

I have an abstract method in a base class declared like so...

```
public abstract void StartHere();
public virtual void StartHere(string flag)
{   
    switch(flag)
    {
        default : StartHere(); break;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to change it so that the inheriting child class is forced to implement one or the other, but not both? Currently the child class is forced to implement only StartHere().

Also would you say its good practice to have the default virtual method point back to the parameterless abstract? or is this just pointless?

The function of this method is to setup the class, the programmer can either do a simple setup using StartHere() or a more complicated one taking in a flag StartHere(string).

Thank you!

Comment: You are giving the client programmer too much rope to hang himself.  Program assertively, take charge of the parts that you should take care of and don't leave it up to somebody else to figure it out.  Make StartHere(string) private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, it would be wise for the parameter less function to call the Para-metered function by passing the default values. This is called Function chaining.

Comment: so you're saying startHere() should call startHere("default")...but then it can't be abstract correct. I would like this method to be abstract to force its implentation.

Comment: Yes. You can keep the startHere with max number of parameters abstract. Or expose methods which would set the attributes of the class which would act as input parameter and let startHere use those attributes / properties

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand how to force one of two abstract methods, but I reversed the order of the calls in another similar method of mine. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot force one of two abstract methods. But you can keep only the parameterized methods abstract and leave the parameter less ones as virtual. This way derived class can override and provide specific implementation if required and must implement parameterized ones.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I guess that's kinda what I'm doing...but in reverse...for my purposes tho the parameterized method is the one that may not be so necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer a different design, something like:

```
public void StartHere();
public virtual void StartHere(string flag)
{
    StartHere();
}
```

Because in this case, the parent class and the child classes are more loosely-coupled: the parent class don't have to know anything about the **flag**s that only child classes are interested in.

If you have to follow your current design for some reason, I suggest you at least change the following lines:

```
    switch(flag)
    {
        default : StartHere(); break;
    }
```

to something like:

```
    switch(flag)
    {
        "DEFAULTFLAG" : StartHere(); break;
        default : throw ArgumentException(
            String.Format("Unrecognized flag '{0}'!", flag)
            );
    }
```

It's easier for you to catch unintended errors when you set wrong flags by mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated my switch.  And may consider removing it all together.